# C# byte file copy hang on filestream.close

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I'm trying to implement a file copy with progress bar in a c# winforms app.
Just a single thread for now.
I'm finding that the file delivery gets to 100% and hangs for ages on filestream.close().
The destination is a UNC path.

What is wrong with my implementation?

```
// Create source and destination file streams
using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
using (var outputFileStream = new FileStream(destPath + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourceFilePath) + ".tfr", FileMode.Create))
{
    long sourceFileSize = inputFileStream.Length;
    int offset = 0;
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int progressPercent;

    while(offset < sourceFileSize)
    {
        // Fill buffer
        inputFileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        // Empty buffer to output stream
        outputFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        // Flush buffer
        //Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // Advance read offset
        offset += bufferSize;

        // Update GUI
        progressPercent = Convert.ToInt32(((double)offset / (double)sourceFileSize) * 100.0);
        pBar.Value = progressPercent;
        pBar.Refresh();
        labUploadStatus.Text = $"Uploading file...{progressPercent}%";
        labUploadStatus.Refresh();
    }

    outputFileStream.Close();
    inputFileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: What Operating System?  Sounds like Window 7.  Try changing extension from tfr to txt to see if it makes a difference.   Also try c:\valid_sub_folder location.  I don't think it is your code.

Comment: How big is the file? And are you writing to a USB drive or a network share drive? Flushing the internal buffer to disk could take a while if the file is large and the drive is slow.

Comment: Running on Win8.1. Created a volume on my ssd and delivered to there - no hang. File is only 10MB for the testing.

Comment: When you say flushing the internal buffer, do I understand right that the whole file might be buffered somewhere and is only being written to the destination (network drive) when I do "outputFileStream.Close(); ?

Comment: @Quantum_Kernel yes, data can be buffered in OS's I/O buffer. If you don't want that to happen manually flush the writer every time you call `Write`. You'll get a more realistic (and slower) progress count if the bottleneck is your destination disk, as it seems to be.

Comment: This seems to be a heuristic that Windows uses. It sometimes flushes all file data when the file is closed. I never found out under what exact circumstances it does this. Windows also sometimes uncaches an entire file on close. I observed that using RAMMap.exe.